# Why doesn't my view remove the selected object?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form to unsubscribe newsletter subscribers, but I don't know exactly where I'm going wrong.  The steps in my view all work in the command line so its hard for me to debug.  When I submit the form on an existing email address the error is 'Subscriber with this email already exists', but I'm trying to delete an object not create one, and I'm a little stuck.  Any help is much appreciated!

My View:

```
from subscribe.forms import SubscribeForm, UnsubscribeForm
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Subscriber

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def unsubscribe(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UnsubscribeForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user = get_object_or_404(Subscriber,email=email)
                user.delete(id=user.id)
                messages.success(request, 'Unsubscribed')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/newsletter/subscribe/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, form.errors)
                return render(request, 'unsubscribe.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = UnsubscribeForm()
        return render(request, 'unsubscribe.html', {'form': form})
```

My forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, EmailField
from .models import Subscriber

    class SubscribeForm(ModelForm):

        email = EmailField()

        class Meta:
            model = Subscriber
            fields = ('email',)


    class UnsubscribeForm(ModelForm):

        email = EmailField()

        class Meta:
            model = Subscriber
            fields = ('email',)
```

My Model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">UnSubscribe</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this statement is causing this error, but I think `user.delete(id=user.id)` should look like `user.delete()`.

Comment: And you don't need to re-declare `email` in `UnsubscribeForm`. It is a `ModelForm`. Specifying `email` in `fields` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  user.delete(id) does work in the console.  The thing that I can't figure out is why I get an error that the object exists, since I'm trying to delete and not create an object, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add the html template too? Or a copy of the request you're making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a working view for the unsubscribe page.  Not really different from before, but the difference was in the model, where I removed the unique constraint from the email field.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75,)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```